# USB Diff Pair used by 2 devices on PCB

Tags: usb, layout, high-speed, usb-hub, usb-c

My PMIC uses the DP/DN pair of USB type C to get the maximum current that it can draw to power up the circuit or charge the battery. The problem is that i don't have a hub and the signal from connector is singular and needs to arrive at CPU.

Could I route it near the PMIC create a little stub near the pad and continue to the CPU like in picture?[image]

Thanks

Comment: Can you link the datasheets for the PMIC and uC?

Comment: yes sure. the PMIC is  TI bq24190 and the CPU is rockchip 3399 (http://opensource.rock-chips.com/images/6/60/Rockchip_RK3399_Datasheet_V1.6-20170301.pdf)

Comment: I also have on PCB  a FUSB302 a programmable usb type c controller w/PD

Comment: You may need to switch to BQ24192 and do the detection in firmware

Comment: There are other versions of this TI part that have a DSEL pin.  The idea being you use a little USB switch from TI before the charger and the rockchip.  At startup the charger runs detection, then when finished flips the switch to connect to your rockchip. Mine only does that when it detects something safe ie not a short on DP/DM.  I can't remember the part I'm using (I'm home) but I do exactly what I describe in one of our products.  Seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

This is a good question. The BQ24xxx line of chargers doesn't seem to provide good care of signal integrity for USB HS (480Mbpd) data rate, since you have to fork the data signals. Your layout looks the best you can do in this situation.

There was a similar inquiry [on TI blog](https://e2e.ti.com/support/power_management/battery_management/f/179/t/528977), with totally meaningless answer without any concern for signal integrity. The pin capacitance is not listed in the BQ24xxx datasheet. If it is 3-5pF as usual, then the transmission line might be only modestly perturbed, and signal eye diagrams might remain acceptable. But who knows, stub capacitors are not improving signals. You should get more traction in Texas Instruments blogosphere if you formulate the signal integrity concern explicitly.

Alternatively you may try a USB mux instead of fork, and do the charging port detection on sideline, but you will need to control the switch separately, and the USB switches are not the best for signal integrity either.